# javascript get the full src url for an img element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I can get the src url of the first image on the page with this

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var image = images[0]; //get first img
var src = image.getAttribute('src');
```

But I have come accross the situation when the src url is:

```
//domain.com/img/icon.png
```

I was able to fix this by adding the line:

```
if (src.substring(0,2) == '//') src = 'http:'+src;
```

But then I ran into more problems. Like what if the url is:

```
'/img/icon.png'
```

or

```
'../img/icon.png'
```

And I don't know if there are still other edge cases I haven't yet found.
Is there any way to query for the full url of the src?

Comment: `image.src` will give you the fully qualified URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You should use the `src` **property** rather than the `src` **attribute**. This is normalized to include the base URL:

```
var src = image.src;
```

See [MDN documentation for `HTMLImageElement.src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement.src).

Comment: Link is no longer there.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `image.getAttribute('src')` which just gets the attribute, you should use `image.src` which will return the full URL.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp